# Ordering sub-categories in A-Z order?

Tags: category, ce-1.7.0.2, phtml

OK I have taken over a store from a group of developers. In **sub-cat.phtml** they are ordering the sub-categories by their ID. I would like to change this to be either the order they're in within admin area or from A-Z. This is the code from the template file:

```
<div class="sub-category">
<?php
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
    $object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
    $actualCategoryId = $object->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    $actualCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($actualCategoryId);
    $subCategories = explode(',', $actualCategory->getChildren());
    $count_sub_cat = count($subCategories);
    $count_sub_cat_half = $count_sub_cat/3;
?>

<ul>

<?php
    $count=1;
    $_iterator = 0;
    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId ) {      
?>

<li class="sub-cat <?php if ($count%4 == 0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">       
    <div class="sub_cat_inner">

        <?php

            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

            if( $category->getIsActive() ) {

                $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
                $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
                $_imgHtml   = '';
                $thumb = $category->getThumbnail();
                echo '<p class="category-image-list"><a href="'.$category->getURL().'">';
                echo '<img src="'.$this->getBaseUrl().'media/catalog/category/'.$thumb.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($category->getName()).'" style="max-width:215px" />';
                echo '</a></p>';
                echo '<a class="cat-name" href="'.$category->getURL().'"><span>'.$category->getName().'</span></a> ';
            }

        ?>

    </div>  
</li>

<?php if($count == $count_sub_cat) echo '</ul>';
    else if ($count%4 == 0) { 
        echo '</ul><ul>';
    }
?>

<?php  $count++; } ?>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if Magento provides an easy method for doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Categories - how to display in alphabetical order? (Programmatically)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/categories-how-to-display-in-alphabetical-order-programmatically)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: My question is different.

Comment: This is really not good code in a Magento template.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt, benmarks: Can you explain one thing to me? How is the above code generating the sub-sub categories? When I debug, it only seems to print out sub-categories of the root cateogry. It's making me very frustrated. Also why is this not good code?

Comment: I would say you are right. This code only creates entries for all categories under the current one and one entry for `$subCategoryId`

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: What's strange is that this is the template associated with this page: http://safaviehhome.com/living-room.html and you can see that it lists the "sub-sub" categories (thumbnail, etc.) .. so I don't see how it's done. This is the template associated with it according  to template path hints. How is this possible?

Comment: if it is badly done, like include() etc. you don't see the templates in the template hints. Just an idea. What I would do is to get a part of the html of the sub categories and find it in magento, then set a break point in xdebug and see what the call path is.

Answer (score 1):

I have change the code check

```
    <div class="sub-category">
<?php
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
    $object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
    $actualCategoryId = $object->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    $actualCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($actualCategoryId);
    $subCategories = explode(',', $actualCategory->getChildren());
    $count_sub_cat = count($subCategories);
    $count_sub_cat_half = $count_sub_cat/3;
?>

<ul>
<?php
    $count=1;
    $_iterator = 0;
    $CatColection= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addNameToResult()
            ->addUrlRewriteToResult()
            ->addIsActiveFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array("in"=>$subCategories))
            ->setOrder('name',ASC);
    foreach ($CatColection as $subCategoryId ) {      
?>

<li class="sub-cat <?php if ($count%4 == 0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">       
    <div class="sub_cat_inner">

        <?php
            $subCategoryId=$subCategory->getId();
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

            if( $category->getIsActive() ) {

                $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
                $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
                $_imgHtml   = '';
                $thumb = $category->getThumbnail();
                echo '<p class="category-image-list"><a href="'.$category->getURL().'">';
                echo '<img src="'.$this->getBaseUrl().'media/catalog/category/'.$thumb.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($category->getName()).'" style="max-width:215px" />';
                echo '</a></p>';
                echo '<a class="cat-name" href="'.$category->getURL().'"><span>'.$category->getName().'</span></a> ';
            }

        ?>

    </div>  
</li>

<?php if($count == $count_sub_cat) echo '</ul>';
    else if ($count%4 == 0) { 
        echo '</ul><ul>';
    }
?>

<?php  $count++; } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working for me. The sub-categories don't show up if I use your code.

Comment: I'm getting the same result after edit :(

Comment: Check now  again.............